# vue: changes not triggered @input

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Below is vue script - the concern method is called notLegalToShip which checks when age < 3.

```js
export default {
  template,
  props: ['child', 'l'],
  created() {
    this.name = this.child.name.slice();
    this.date_of_birth = this.child.date_of_birth.slice();
  },
  data() {
    return {
      edit: false,
      today: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
      childUnder3: false
    };
  },
  computed: {
    age() {
      var today = new Date();
      var birthDate = new Date(this.child.date_of_birth);
      var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
      var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
      if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
      }
      return age;
    }
  },
  methods: Object.assign(
    mapActions(['updateChild']),
    {
      notLegalToShip() {
        if(this.age < 3){
          this.childUnder3 = true;
        }
        this.childUnder3 = false; 
      },
      showForm() {
        this.edit = true;
      },
      hideForm() {
        this.edit = false;
      },
      submitForm() {
        this.hideForm();
        this.updateChild({
          child: this.child,
          name: this.name,
          dateOfBirth: this.date_of_birth,
          childUnder3 : this.childUnder3
        });
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Here's the snippet of my template. The input as below. 
[image]
I want the notLegalToShip method to be triggered when I click arrow changing the year. A warning will appear when childUnder3 is "true". I've tried @change, @input on my input but my method is not triggered at all:

```html
<div>
  {{childUnder3}}
  {{age}}
  <div class="callout danger" v-if="childUnder3">
      <h2>Sorry</h2>
      <p>Child is under 3!</p>
  </div>
  <div v-if="!edit">
    <a @click.prevent="showForm()" href="#" class="more-link edit-details edit-child">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{ l.child.edit_details }}
    </a>
  </div>
  <form v-show="edit" @submit.prevent="submitForm()">
    <div class="input-wrap">
      <label for="account__child__date-of-birth__date">{{ l.child.date_of_birth }}</label>
      <input id="account__child__date-of-birth__date" type="date" name="date_of_birth" v-on:input="notLegalToShip" v-model="date_of_birth" v-validate="'required'">
      <p class="error-message" v-show="errors.has('date_of_birth')">{{ l.child.date_of_birth_invalid }}</p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Any help checking my code above would be appreciated!

Comment: You haven't defined the `name` and `date_of_birth` properties in `data()` so they won't be reactive

Comment: Actually name and date_of_birth were not defined to begin with but other things worked before this. It's just my warning div won't come up.

Comment: If you want Vue to react to changes (in this case, your `age` computed property reacts to `date_of_birth`), you need to define all properties within the `data()` initialiser

Comment: @Phil I've defined in my data -  name: ' ', dateOfBirth: this.date_of_birth but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems...

1. Initialise the `name` and `date_of_birth` properties in the `data()` initialiser so Vue can react to them. You can even initialise them from your `child` prop there...

   ```js
   data() {
     return {
       edit: false,
       today: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
       name: this.child.name // no need to use slice, strings are immutable
       date_of_birth: this.child.date_of_birth
     }
   }
   ```
2. Use `this.date_of_birth` inside your `age` computed property instead of `this.child.date_of_birth`. This way, it will react to changes made via your `v-model="date_of_birth"` input element.
3. Make `childUnder3` a computed property, it will be easier that way

   ```js
   childUnder3() {
     return this.age < 3
   }
   ```

   Alternately, ditch this and just use `v-if="age < 3"`

With the above, you no longer need any `@input` or `@change` event listeners.

Comment: @nothingme that's great. Happy to help